# slimScroll - mousewheel propagate to body (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

How to avoid the mousewheel to propagate to body in Firefox?

This works perfect in both Chrome and IE11, but in Firefox the mousewheel propagate to the body.

```
content.slimScroll({
    position: 'right',
    height: height_content,
    railVisible: true,
    alwaysVisible: true
});
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cfuqzpv5)

Comment: what Firefox version do you have and can you make a jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Can't replicate on Firefox 34 for OS X. http://jsfiddle.net/cfuqzpv5/

Comment: @nit, this doesn't work for me.. When using the mousewheel over the overflow element, the mousewheel propagate to the body :-/

Comment: You still have not answered what Firefox version you're using. Find out [**here**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-what-version-firefox-you-are-using). This seems to be a related issue with Firefox 33 and below since I can't replicate the issue in your JsFiddle with Firefox 34. Consider updating it.

Answer (score 1):

when I try your fiddle using my Waterfox (64bit ver of firefox), yes it actually propagate to body if I use (laptop) touchpad scroll, but not with my actual mouse scroll (wheel)

then I try go to [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) official site, then I try with touchpad it doesn't propagate to body, when I look the version of slimScroll used is `1.3.0` and in there say latest stable version is actually `1.3.0`, but on your fiddle you are using version `1.3.3`

my conclusion is maybe version `1.3.3` is not stable yet, I would suggest you to use the stable version from official website

---

*ps: I try change your fiddle slimScroll js with what used in official website*

`http://rocha.la/misc/jsdemos/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js`

and viola it not propagate to body